# Ember Dynamically Generated HTML

Tags: ember.js

I have a requirement where I need to add html after the DOM has been rendered.
I was wondering if it is possible to manipulate the DOM after creation and dynamically add html and also specifying an associated ember action.

E.g. The intension of what I want to achieve:

```
 $('.add').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    i += 1;
    var content = "<div class=\"item dodgerBlue\"><h1>"+i+"</h1></div>";
    var content + "{{action "owlItemClicked" titleModel.id titleModel.index titleModel on="click" }}"
    owl.data('owlCarousel').addItem(content);
  });
```

Specifically I want to add another Item to my carousel:
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/manipulations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the triple-stash, which just includes content without escaping it, will work with an {{action}}. In any case, it looks to me that you'd be better off simply defining the html within an each block and letting Ember handle the content addition.

```
{{#each model as |titleModel index|}}
  <div class=\"item dodgerBlue\">
    <h1>{{index}}</h1>
  </div>
  {{action "owlItemClicked" titleModel.id titleModel.index titleModel on="click" }}
{{/each}}
```

I noticed you have a titleModel.index property, so maybe you don't need the index in each block and can use the model's property instead.

That would be the Ember way to do it. However, it looks like this OwlCarousel widget wants to have the html passed directly. But there's also a reinit method, so maybe that would be sufficient to tell it that new content has been added through Ember. Something like the following:

```
carouselOptions: {
  // ...
},

didInsertElement: function() {
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
    var $c = Ember.$('#the-carousel');
    if ($c.length) {
      $c.owlCarousel( this.get('carouselOptions') );
    }
  });
},

actions: {
  addCarouselItem: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Add a new item to your array.
    // Not shown because i have no idea of your code.
    // Ember will handle DOM insert.
    // Then reinit carousel.
    $("#the-carousel").data('owlCarousel').reinit( this.get('carouselOptions') );
  },

  owlItemClicked: function(e) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian - I have already attempted it doing the ember way. What happens is the owl plugin manipulates the Dom. Which somehow results in the div elements being unbound from the underlying model(s). So even if I remove/add a model the Dom doesn't update. Hence why I want to use an alternative approach. Will give your owl way of doing it a go in a couple of hours and will let you know how it went. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can insert dynamically created HTML using the [triple-stache](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping) in your template.

```
// controller.js
dynamicHtml: Ember.computed({
    get() {
        return `<div>Hello World!</div>`;
    }
})

...

{{! template.hbs }}
{{{dynamicHtml}}}
```

Comment: How do I associate an ember action with this approach? E.g If I want to generate an action on click hello world div tag

Comment: Sorry, deleted my last comment. The HTMLBars runtime compiler doesn't work the same as the Handlebars runtime compiler. Ember really advises against using dynamic HTML, so it's not very well documented. So unfortunately, I don't have a complete answer to your question.